# How to change Activity As background color from Activity B in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

In my app I'm trying to change my `Activity`'s background color. For example from `Activity` B I should be able to change the background of `Activity` A, how can I do this? I tried `findViewById`, but app crashes. Any solutions? Thank you very much!

P.S: I'm using AmbilWarna ColorPicker!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it from another activity.

**Code:**

Since it seems you want to do it in your activity here is how, simply use the code

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.YourActivityId);
v.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

The color in this case is either something like `Color.GREEN` or you can define your own color in your colors.xml.

For more information on defining colors look at the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

Comment: No! I want to change the color from another Activity. Means if I am on the Activity of Settings for example, then from that Activity I should be able to change Home Screen's Activity color. Got it?

Comment: One moment, let me fix my answer

Comment: Yep sure take your time :-)

Comment: It's force closing :'-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78569/discussion-between-tristan-wiley-and-ajinkya-more).